# I have installed kubeflow pipeline but not have jupyter notebook in UI

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, jupyter-notebook, kubeflow

I have installed kubeflow pipeline in mac M1 but not able to see "notebook" option in UI.
[image]

I have used these step

```
# env/platform-agnostic-pns hasn't been publically released, so you will install it from master
export PIPELINE_VERSION=2.0.1
kubectl apply -k "github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/manifests/kustomize/cluster-scoped-resources?ref=$PIPELINE_VERSION"
kubectl wait --for condition=established --timeout=60s crd/applications.app.k8s.io
kubectl apply -k "github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/manifests/kustomize/env/platform-agnostic-pns?ref=$PIPELINE_VERSION"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install all components using the following link:
https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests

•   sudo snap install kustomize

•   git clone https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests.git

•   cd manifests

•   while ! kustomize build example | kubectl apply -f -; do echo "Retrying to apply resources"; sleep 10; done

•   After installation, it will take some time for all Pods to become ready. Make sure all Pods are ready before trying to connect, otherwise you might get unexpected errors. To check that all Kubeflow-related Pods are ready, use the following commands:
o   kubectl get pods -n cert-manager
o   kubectl get pods -n istio-system
o   kubectl get pods -n auth
o   kubectl get pods -n knative-eventing
o   kubectl get pods -n knative-serving
o   kubectl get pods -n kubeflow
o   kubectl get pods -n kubeflow-user-example-com

•   Port-Forward:
The default way of accessing Kubeflow is via port-forward. This enables you to get started quickly without imposing any requirements on your environment. Run the following to port-forward Istio's Ingress-Gateway to local port 8080:
kubectl port-forward svc/istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system 8080:80
After running the command, you can access the Kubeflow Central Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Notebooks is a separate component in kubeflow. So you will need to install it separately. I would highly recommend that you install kubeflow as per the process documented on offical website
https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/started/installing-kubeflow/

This way you will need not to install all the core components individually.